# How to create a SQL statement which returns first positive after that negative IDs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I need a SQL statement which returns first the positive IDs 1,2,3 and after that the negative IDs -1, -2, -3 and so on.

I need this in one sql statement for MS SQL Server. May anyone write an example of a sql statement? Thanks a lot for every helpful answer!

That's currently the output:

```
ID  |  name
-46 |  TestA
-45 |  TestB
...
1   |  TestK
2   |  TestL
...
134 |  TestC
```

I need this result:

```
ID  | name
134 | TestC
1   | TestK
2   | TestL
-46 | TestA
-45 | TestB
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So, I have solved my own problem.
Here is my SQL statement, which works great :)

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM TblName
WHERE Name LIKE '[a-z]%'
ORDER BY SIGN(Id) DESC, Name
```

This statement sorted the data by Name but shows at first the names with positive IDs and after that the negative IDs!

Comment: this is a repost of my answer

Comment: @nicholas sorry but in your answer was missing the WHERE-clause.

Comment: the where clause is not necessary based on your original question (and the final version of the question) - the WHERE would only be required if you have some non-alpha or null entries in the name

Answer (score 2):

Try using UNION:

```
SELECT id
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE id >= 0
ORDER BY id
UNION
SELECT id
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE id < 0
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: You can use the order by at the end of the query only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP 3 ID FROM TBL WHERE ID > 0 ORDER BY ID
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 3 ID FROM TBL WHERE ID < 0 ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: You can use the order by at the end of the query only.

Comment: @Hebele I want to sort the name not the ID.. how can I do that?

Comment: @yuro Show output please.

Comment: @Hebele You mustn't use two times the ORDER BY-clause. At the end of the statement only!

Answer (score 0):

You want to first order by sign, and then by magnitude. Try:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM TBL ORDER BY SIGN(ID) DESC, Name
```

Comment: @yuro, just add the name field to the select statement then

Comment: I will try this at work tomorrow. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: This doesn't sort the list by name! It is sorting by the IDs. Look to my edited post.

Comment: @yuro, changed it to do negative IDs, positive IDs, then by name. FYI: changing questions is not good SO form. something as subtle as the secondary sort behavior is almost too trivial for this site.